# PHP/mySQL: how to debug a 'too many connections' error?

Tags: mysql, connection

I am working right now with PHP website on my client's dedicated server and I get periodically an error `too many connections` but ~5 users are browsing this page.

In `phpMyAdmin` I can see that `max connections` variable is set to `400`.

On our local MySQL server in my corporation we have `max connections` set to `200` and other mates uses in the same time this server.

I heard that on their server some other web is using the same MySQL with big trafiic.

Here are my questions:

- How to debug this problem?
- Can I look into some list of SQL queries that was executed in last 10 minutes to check if it is our problem or their?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptoms you describe point to persistent connections. In some setups PHP does not handle persistent connections very well: it tends to open new connections rather than reuse the existing ones. I suggest you disable this feature and see if the issue persists:

- At code level: find calls to [mysql_pconnect()](http://es.php.net/mysql_pconnect) and replace them with [mysql_connect()](http://es.php.net/mysql_connect).
- At configuration level: find the [mysql.allow_persistent](http://es.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.allow-persistent) directive and set it to false.

If you notice an improvement, you can try to fine tune persistent calls or get rid of them permanently.

Comment: I also shoot that case. At all I can not modify their web/server configuration to make that changes (my web does not uses `persistent connections` anywhere). Tomorrow I am going to meet their man and I will ask them to do that.

Comment: This doesn't require modifying any server configuration. You would just need to update the PHP scripts for the application.

Comment: Sure, but I have no access to the second webpage which is also using the same MySql server - so I can not update their PHP script that may uses `mysql_pconnect`. `phpinfo()` shows me that ` mysql.allow_persistent` is `On`. Changing that flag to `Off` will not give any results at all - it should be changet on their machine.

Comment: They changed `mysql.allow_persistent` to `Off` and our CMS accelerated and now there are no problems with connections. Thanks! But I am still wondering how to check what scripts was connecting with MySql server?

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST tells you the user, host, DB and (if you're lucky) query.

Comment: But it will show me only current processes, right ? Are not there something like query history ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html